# How can I dub an audio track over a video I'm making with avconv?

Tags: sound, video, avconv

So to start out with, I having figured out how to animate a number of still frames into a video, like this:

```
avconv -f image2 -i %06d.png -r 24 -qscale 1 aniron.avi
```

I have a bunch of files in the directory named 000000.png, 000001.png, 000002.png. I am able to make a video of sufficiently high quality this way. However, efforts to add an audio track by putting "-i aniron.mp3" and a few other options have failed thus far. I always get this:

```
avconv version 0.8.5-4:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav 
developers
  built on Jan 24 2013 18:03:14 with gcc 4.6.3
[mp3 @ 0x8623aa0] max_analyze_duration reached
[mp3 @ 0x8623aa0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'aniron.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    TDTG            : 2012-07-28T18:05:36
  Duration: 00:07:11.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 191 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
Input #1, image2, from '%06d.png':
  Duration: 00:07:09.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1.0: Video: png, rgb24, 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'aniron.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Incompatible pixel format 'rgb24' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x8629500] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:rgb24
[avsink @ 0x8657d60] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the
filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x8634940] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:rgb24 -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'ac3', auto-selecting format 'flt'
[ac3 @ 0x86438e0] invalid bit rate
Output #0, avi, to 'aniron.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    TDTG            : 2012-07-28T18:05:36
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: ac3, 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 200 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (png -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> ac3)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such
as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I may just end up doing this in Kdenvlive but this is bugging me.

Comment: The problem appears to be that by default it is trying to re-encode your input MP3 into AC3 format. This is causing an error since the AC3 encoder apparently doesn't like 16bit samples (I suspect it prefers more). By adding `-c:a copy` after `-i somefile.mp3` it should re-use the MP3 input rather than transcoding it.

Answer (score 3):

```
avconv -f image2 -i %06d.png -r 24 -qscale 1 -i audiofile.mp3 -c:a copy aniron.avi
```

Things to note:

- `-c:a` determines the output audio codec - we just copy the one from the input file here
- The avi container is quite lacking, for example, you might get sync problems if your mp3 file is VBR. A better alternative would be MP4 or MKV.
- You might specify the output video codec (`-c:v`) if you don't like the default one
- As for `ffmpeg` vs. `avconv`: `ffmpeg` is far from deprecated - this is deliberately misleading. If you're interested [read this](http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html)

Comment: for the record: I dont't see anyone in this thread suggesting ffmpeg was deprecated: Sadiq asked if it might be. I answered that is wasnt. If that was the reason the other was downvoted, please read more carefull. Cheers.

Comment: Yes I know, but I didn't downvote your answer ;D

Comment: Alright phoibos, I had sucess with your answer ... after a fashion. It worked after I permuted the arguments. I'm going to submit what worked, upvote your answer, but accept mine.

Answer (score 1):

How about using **ffmpeg** on the **avi** you created?
Syntax would be something like:

```
ffmpeg -i sound.wav -i input.avi output.mpg
```

I an not sure if it will take **mp3** as **audio import** so you might have to do a conversion of your soundfile.

Gd luck

Comment: I'll consider it but isn't ffmpeg deprecated? That means it might disappear soon. I'm sort of uncomfortable with using it then. Anyway, right now I'm wrestling with kdenlive, sigh...

Comment: I don't think its deprecated. There has been a Libav fork off ffmpeg but the latter is still being developped.

Comment: I think I figured out the voodoo I need to get the ugly black bars out of the kdenlive video. Thanks for the help anyway. I'll let you know whether it works shortly.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. Virtually same error as before. And I hate to say it but I do get the message "This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead."

Comment: `ffmpeg` and `avconv` are the results of a rather acrimonious splitting of the original `ffmpeg` project. At this time the syntax and capabilities of the two are very similar. Debian (upon which Ubuntu is based) has chosen in theory to follow the `avconv` rather than `ffmpeg` fork, but it is unlikely that the latter will cease to be available.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in that all arguments were respected; the output was what I wanted, in great quality:

```
avconv -f image2 -i %06d.png -i aniron.mp3 -c:a copy -r 24 -qscale 1 test.avi
```

Order of arguments is a subtle annoyance in avconv and ffmpeg.